# Update on Using Selenium To Scrape Java Heavy Websites in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My first bit of code looked a little like this,

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/13pm9juR7WPjAf7EVWgq5EQAaRTppu2EE7ReuEL9jpkHQMJCjn9")

earnings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('text-base text-gray-600 mb-1 tracking-tight w-full break-all')

print(earnings)

driver.quit()
```

Now I have gotten to the point of adding wait times, but still returns as nothing with this code here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/13pm9juR7WPjAf7EVWgq5EQAaRTppu2EE7ReuEL9jpkHQMJCjn9")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='app']/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]")))
finally:
    earnings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]')
    print(earnings)
    print("loaded")
    driver.quit()
```

I am just trying to scrape the text with the dollar amount on it in this container
[Image of Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4ZSw.png)

Would love some further help on this problem I am having.

Comment: In `earnings` you are trying to find element using `find_elements` which return a list of webelements. If you are trying to find a single element use `find_element`. Then `print(earnings)` will print the webelement data. `print(earnings.text)` will print `$18.20`, the text inside the element.

Comment: Comes back with error, "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'"

Answer (score 0):

As already explained `find_elements` will return `List of WebElements` and access those you can use indexing - `earnings[0]`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/13pm9juR7WPjAf7EVWgq5EQAaRTppu2EE7ReuEL9jpkHQMJCjn9")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='app']/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]")))
finally:
    earnings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]')
    print(earnings[0].text)
    print("loaded")
driver.quit()
```

And `find_element` will return a `WebElement` and access the same:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='app']/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]")))
finally:
    earnings = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]')
    print(earnings.text)
    print("loaded")
```

For both the output was:

```
$14.08
loaded
```